# Safari: Promise "syntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'function'. Expected ')' "

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

This code works in Chrome, but fails with Subject's syntax error in Safari in line 2.
Also, in iOS the Safari user is asked for permission to use their microphone but recording fails. All is well with Android Chrome.

[Fiddle shows more](https://jsfiddle.net/x63of7b8/)

[Code is based on](https://github.com/bryanjenningz/record-audio)

index.js:

```
var recordAudio = function recordAudio() {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve) {
    var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    });
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    var audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function(event) {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    var start = function start() {
      audioChunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.start();
    };

    var stop = function stop() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function() {
          var audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
          var audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
          var audio = new Audio(audioUrl);

          var play = function play() {
            return audio.play();
          };

          resolve({
            audioChunks: audioChunks,
            audioBlob: audioBlob,
            audioUrl: audioUrl,
            play: play
          });
        });
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      });
    };

    resolve({
      start: start,
      stop: stop
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: This means Safari doesn't support the `async` keyword. What version of Safari is it? It has been supported since 10.1.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: @Barmar it's Safari 9.1.2 . But my kids have tried it on iOS 14. But I do not have an iOS device and would not know how to get at the developer's stuff on a mobile device. Btw, the app is currently at https://contracalls.appspot.com . But only works on non-iOS Chrome as far as I can tell. Maybe you can test it on a newer Safari?

Comment: Safari 9 is 5 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `async` functions was added in Safari 10.1. You're doing your testing in 9.1, which is too old.

If you need your application to be compatible with such an old Safari version (it's from 2016) you'll have to use explicit `Promise` code rather than `async` and `await`.

Comment: On Safari 13.1.3 I get "Line 9:47 Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MediaRecorder"  Line 9  contains `var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);` I want it to work on mobiles only, btw

Comment: You need to learn to use caniuse.com to find out what features are available in different Safari versions. MediaRecorder is available by default in 14.1, can be enabled in 12.1, and isn't available before that.

Comment: Safari 9.1 is way out of date, you should forget about trying to support it.

Comment: My target is iOS. caniuse (thanks) says it is available by default in 14.5, but my testers had only 14.4 . How is it made to work in the versions like  12.1 on Mac and iOS ? Can the app make it work, or does the individural user have to do something?

Comment: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-enable-the-mediarecorder-api-for-safari

Comment: That link almost works for the 13.1.3 (laptop). It leaves out a (required?) step to leave Safari preferences before (and restart Safari, perhaps) using the mic. But then the system preferences for sound input may need to be adjusted and monitored to see if sound is being heard. But even after all that, I was not able to hear the recordings play. But I am not totally discouraged because my real target is the iphone Safari. But I don't have an iphone so I'm going to ask my  "testers" (relatives) to try it out. If anyone here gets a success I would appreciate getting feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `Promise` and `async` syntax, the error from Safari is telling you that it doesn't expect an `async` function, which makes sense as you're resolving a promise with another promise.

Change `function recordAudio` to `async function recordAudio` and remove the `new Promise` entirely and just use `await` instead.

Any function that uses `await` will return a `Promise` anyway.

```
async function recordAudio() {
    var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    });
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    var audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function(event) {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    var start = function start() {
      audioChunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.start();
    };

    var stop = function stop() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function() {
          var audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
          var audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
          var audio = new Audio(audioUrl);

          var play = function play() {
            return audio.play();
          };

          resolve({
            audioChunks: audioChunks,
            audioBlob: audioBlob,
            audioUrl: audioUrl,
            play: play
          });
        });
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      });
    };

    return {
      start: start,
      stop: stop
    };
};
```

Comment: While it might not make sense, it doesn't seem like it would be a syntax error.

Comment: Syntax-wise, it's just an ordinary function call.

Comment: @Barmar `async` says _function returns a Promise_, I'd guess Safari is checking for that. `async` is just syntax sugar, so while it _can_ be a synchronous call with no `await` it may well be a syntax error in places where Safari's engine needs the function to be synchronous.

Comment: I just tried `y = new Promise(async function() { return 2; })` in the Safari 13.1.2 console. No error.

Comment: @Barmar the function you create a promise with shouldn't be a promise. Maybe Safari's compiler can resolve that trivial case? I don't know. Safaris supports `async` and the error message points to the `function` in `async function` being the problem.

Comment: @Keith it's highly unlikely that Safari would find *syntax* errors like that, because they're *not* syntax errors.

Comment: @Keith I get another syntax error on the first line of your code: "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'function'. Expected ';' after var declaration." Btw, my index.js begins with `"use strict";` and I did not mention that.

Comment: @zerowords Hmm, try replacing `var recordAudio = async function recordAudio()` with `async function recordAudio()` or `var recordAudio = async function()` as you don't need the name twice.

Comment: @Keith I tried your second suggestion and got the same SyntaxError as your previous correction. I did not try your first suggestion because it  had no = sign or left hand to = sign.

Comment: @zerowords yes, you don't need the `=` at all. It's valid JS but it appears to be `async function`  as an assignment rather than a declaration that Safari doesn't like. Try either the declaration syntax (no `=`) or see if lambda syntax works: `var recordAudio = async () => {...`